# Integrate $\int \frac{dx}{a + bx^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to integrate

$$\int \frac{dx}{a + bx^2}$$ for $ab \neq 0$.

I've managed to do the following:

$$\int \frac{dx}{a + bx^2} = \frac 1a \int \frac{dx}{1 + \left(\sqrt{\frac ba} x\right)^2} = \frac{1}{a} \sqrt{\frac ab} \arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac ba} \cdot x\right) + C$$

with the substitution $u = \sqrt{\frac ba} x$.

The above equation is only valid if $ab>0$. I'm not quite sure what to do if $ab < 0$ despite thinking about it for some time. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $ab<0$ then you will have the inverse hyperbolic tangent: $$\text{arctanh}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $ab<0$, you can rewrite the function as
$$
\frac{1}{b}\frac{1}{\frac{a}{b}+x^2}
$$
Set $a/b=-c^2$, with $c>0$ and do the substitution $x=ct$, so you are reduced (up to numeric factors) to the integral of
$$
\frac{1}{t^2-1}
$$
that you can do by partial fractions.

Answer (score 0):

Then you should use this formula $$\int \frac{1}{1 - x^2} dx = \int \frac{1}{2(1 - x)} dx + \int \frac{1}{2(1 + x)} dx$$